# Google sheet : xlookup date and return with multiple value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been making a project that will lookup for a specific date then return all cells value with that specific date.
For example:
Column A (date) : 8-7-23 | 8-8-23 | 8-9-23 | 8-7-23 | 8-8-23
Column B         : apple | orange | grapes | berry  | apple

When I xlookup 8-7-23, return should be apple | berry

is it possible ?
TYIA

Been trying to use the basic xlookup but only 1 value was return.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try with [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function:*

```
=filter(B:B,A:A=D2)
```

[image]